# Cordova/PhoneGap InAppBrowser not working at all

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I've looked at several other solutions, but none are quite like mine.  Most work one way or another, but for me it doesn't work at all, whether I use straight link markup or an onclick function with window.open().

The app always opens the link in the default Cordova WebView. I've tried "_blank" and "_system". I also checked to see if the plugin was correctly added to my config.xml file, and it was.

Since I'm testing on Android it's not a big deal because I have a back button, but for iOS this becomes a problem.

Cordova Version: 3.5

```
<script>        
    function openGoogle() {
        window.open("https://www.google.com/", "_blank");
    }
</script>
<p id="lh_home"><a href="#" onclick="openGoogle()">www.google.com</a></p>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Once I got onDeviceReady it worked using JS. I'll post details below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. My problem was I was including phonegap.js instead of cordova.js. Embarrassing, I know.

I wasn't able to get it working with the normal link markup, but using the following JS worked.

```
<script>
function openExternal(url) {
    window.open(url, "_blank");
}
</script>
<p id="lh_home"><a href="#" onclick="openExternal('https://www.google.com/')">www.google.com</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Intel XDK, you can also use intel.xdk.device.launchExternal("http://example.com");//open the url in a browser

If you want the browser to be displayed within your app, try intel.xdk.device.showRemoteSite("http://www.example.com/",280,0,50,50);//open the app within the app